# VS2017 MAC Xaml preview window broken

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Installed latest VS 2017 (Version 7.3.3 (build 5)).  Open an XAML file and I get the following error in XAML preview pane:

MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ac] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:237 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse] (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00001] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:241 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.RenderXamls (MonoTouch.Design.DesignSession session, MonoTouch.Design.XamlRenderContext context) [0x0000e] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/Connection/ServerProcessConnection.cs:175 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.iOSXamlRenderer+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 (MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection c) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview/iOS/iOSXamlRenderer.cs:56 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+<>c__DisplayClass265_0`1[TResult].<EnsureSession>b__0 () [0x002bb] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:1919 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.iOSXamlRenderer+d__2.MoveNext () [0x001ed] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.126.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview/iOS/iOSXamlRenderer.cs:56

**I have the following as menvironmentnt:**

Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.3.3 (build 5)
Installation UUID: a1c9c16a-1239-42c5-be68-52c55648e6e4
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 504010007
```

NuGet
Version: 4.3.1.4445

.NET Core
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    2.0.0
    1.1.1
    1.0.4
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    2.0.0
    1.0.3
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Xamarin.Android
Version: 8.1.3.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/XXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        6.0   (API level 23)
        7.0   (API level 24)
        7.1   (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.1

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.2 (13772)
Build 9C40b

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.6.1.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: f70a1348
Branch: xcode9.2
Build date: 2017-12-18 14:47:16-0500

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 4.0.0.215 (Visual Studio Community)

Can someone point me in the right direction to start troubshooting?  I have tried reinstalling, refreshing my PCLs, and now want to roll back XCode, but prior I wanted to post to see if anyone is experience this also.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem.  It was a package called TK.CustomMap.  I had updated to the "2.0" package which created the issues.  I think it was using .NET standard vs. PCL.  now its working since rolling back to 1.6.1.  Something with the preview window and updated third-party packages.  My advice is to update each package one at a time and check everything and not try to be an update hero and update all the packages and wonder why it stopped working!